# gedit lags when changing cursor position

Tags: 14.10, gedit

With Ubuntu 14.10, gedit lags extremely even when only navigating C++ files. Meaning changing the cursor position sometimes takes up to a second. Is this known?

Comment: I'm running gedit and just tried to open a 16MB file and it's always responsive...  Are you running any weird plugins?  Is this happening in the guest session as well?

Comment: Disabled all plugins, and still lagging. Really annoying.

Comment: And in the guest session?

Comment: Same in guest session. Seems to be drawing related, since totem suffers from the same problem. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721

Solved by upgrading gedit (and totem) to 3.12.